Struggling to set Lottie stage when DOM loads
I'm facing a challenge with dynamically setting the stage of a Lottie upon the DOM content being fully loaded. My goal is to randomly select a Lottie and a specific stage in it, and then display the animation starting from the selected stage. However, despite my efforts, the animation does not start from any stage. Any insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // List of the Lotties
    var lottieFiles = [
        {
            path: 'lottie1.json',
            stages: [
                { from: 0, to: 50 },
                { from: 51, to: 100 },
                { from: 101, to: 150 },
                { from: 151, to: 200 }
            ]
        },
        {
            path: 'lottie2.json',
            stages: [
                { from: 0, to: 60 },
                { from: 61, to: 120 },
                { from: 121, to: 180 },
                { from: 181, to: 240 }
            ]
        },
        {
            path: 'lottie3.json',
            stages: [
                { from: 0, to: 40 },
                { from: 41, to: 80 },
                { from: 81, to: 120 },
                { from: 121, to: 160 }
            ]
        },
        {
            path: 'lottie4.json',
            stages: [
                { from: 0, to: 70 },
                { from: 71, to: 140 },
                { from: 141, to: 210 },
                { from: 211, to: 280 }
            ]
        }
    ];

    // Choose random Lottie
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * lottieFiles.length);
    var selectedLottie = lottieFiles[randomIndex];

    // Choose random stage
    var randomStageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * selectedLottie.stages.length);
    var selectedStage = selectedLottie.stages[randomStageIndex];

    // Load the selected Lottie from it's stage
    var animation = lottie.loadAnimation({
        container: document.getElementById('lottie-animation'),
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: true,
        autoplay: true,
        path: selectedLottie.path
    });

    animation.goToAndStop(randomStageIndex.from, true);
});

I was trying to solve the issue by refining the stage selection logic. I revisited the script and adjusted how it identifies and sets the animation stage. Specifically, I made changes to directly specify the stage for the animation without relying on a random index. However, it still shows up at the wrong stage.

I don't know how Lottie works, but you're using randomStageIndex.from which doesn't make sense because randomStageIndex is a number. Did you mean to use selectedStage.from?

Thank you @Halcyon for bringing this to my attention. I already thought I was going crazy
